# Linking an External Stylesheet (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I am building my first website and I'm trying to attach an external css file...

Both my `index.html` and `test.css` are in the exact same folder/directory, but for some reason my `test.css` file isn't being linked...

**Question:** Does anyone know why my `test.css` isn't being linked?

//HTML (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="test.css">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>header of type 1</h1>
    <p>standard paragraph</p>
    <hr>
    <p>HTML stands for Hyper Text Markup Language</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its most likely related to the file path of the external stylesheet... you have `mystyle.css` declaring that this file is in the same directory as your html file .....for example say you had your html file in the following directory `/www/html/index.html` and if you declare `mystyle.css` then your saying that it is located here `/www/html/mystyle.css` in the same directory... so if it's not in the same directory then move it to the same directory... or you can simply change the path you linking it to, but for trial/error just move your `mystyle.css` to the same directory as your `index.html`

Comment: rename your file to `test.css` to make it simple, and read my comment above about adding it to the same directory as your `index.html`

Comment: You should have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">` where some directory `/this/is/a/dir/path/` contains both your `index.html` and `test.css`

Comment: I am looking over this now, the files are in the same directory, but I am double checking if there is an anomaly of sorts

Comment: You should stop using spaces in file names. Might not be related to the problem here, but it is bad practice in general. If you do use spaces, you would have to properly URL-encode them, when you use them in a URL. (Although automatic error correction will kick in here, so it usually “works” – but it is still wrong.) Using f.e. an underscore instead of a space means you don’t need to think about that.

Comment: I'll start doing that from now on, thank you :)

Comment: So change both the name of the file `test.css` which is in the same dir as you confirmed it was, and the link in the html to reflect the name change `href="test.css"`

Comment: rather than just change the name, I also made a new file from scratch following your advice, and thanks to the advice of a previous comment, changed a setting which I think caused the problem as explained in my answer, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Perfect! glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thank you for all the quick responses, I have cleaned up my style thanks to both replies and I have kind of found the solution. I think "user5375312" was on the right track with the .css.css idea, that by adding .css I was somehow adding it twice. I don't think that's "exactly" what happened, but by creating a new css file, when I made it .css I also unchecked the "hide extension" box, which revealed a .txt, making my final file "Test.css.txt"
I removed the .txt keeping only the .css, saved the file to the same location, updated my page and the css file loaded in fine.

I'm still not sure what exactly went wrong or where, but I know it was either when  I created the file the .txt was somehow still present when with previous files it was overridden or removed (something unique to creating css files maybe) or it was after I made the file, that some other setting caused it, but unchecking the hide extension box and making sure it saved correctly solved the problem, and I hope if anyone else encounters the issue that this helps.

Thanks again for the responses, it probably would have been days before I thought figured this out on my own, it was the mention of the .css.css possibility that drew that checkbox to my attention on my4th attempt at making a css file :D

Comment: except your own or some one else's answer and close your question out.

Comment: I'm new to this, won't let me accept my own answer for 2 days? But if I accept another, it might not be clear for others with the same problem, I think I'll leave it and come back when it lets me accept my own

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry, there's nothing wrong with your css code.
You just have to make sure that the 'href' part of your stylesheet link contains the name of the file your want to include, which in your case would be:

```
href="CSS Test.css"
```

Windows will hide the file extensions by default though, so make sure your file isn't actually called "CSS Test.css.css" after you added the extension a second time. To show all file extensions, do the following:

> Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.
>
> Click the View tab, and then, under Advanced settings, clear the Hide extensions for known file types check box, and then click OK.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I have two files, "mistily.css" and "CSS Test.css" I have been bouncing between them in my search for errors, but neither css file seems to work, I'll edit my post for clarity

Comment: Ah, i was hopeful with the css.css thing, I checked and that doesn't seem to be it, I am double checking though, just in case I missed something, it sounds like it's on the right track as I think how I saved the file might have something to do with the problem